# Looking for an appropriate English name to replace my Chinese name

Tags: translation, names, nicknames, cultural-correctness, chinese

#### Background:

I am Chinese, and after living abroad from China for several years, I realize that I need an English name anyway. I’ve seen too many confused faces looking at my Chinese name.

#### My Chinese Name:

I am male, my Chinese first name is (IPA): /ʃəʊ/-/dəʊ/, and my family name is: /dʒi/. (Check ipa-reader.xyz if not clear.)

Any advice about what could be a good idea of a first name, if the last name sounds like "G"?

#### Something about myself:

I'm a introvert, nerdy person. I don't like social, small talk, public area. I enjoy programming, writing, arguing. Physically I am short, slim, with a huge glasses.

Comment: This is not the appropriate place to ask this question, or to find an objective answer. A quick search gave me two articles that might provide some guidance: [Chinese to English translation and transliteration of Chinese names](https://www.chinatranslations.com/chinese-to-english-translation-of-chinese-names.html) and [This Woman Helps Chinese People Choose Better English Names — Here's Why It's So Important](https://www.popsugar.com/smart-living/How-Chinese-People-Choose-English-Names-38760151).

Comment: I've read similar things, however, does the implicit meaning of the name matters? For example, someone said to me I am definitely not a "Sean", or "David", I'm still confused about what the image that the name gives, I thinks this is not simply converting based on the pronunciation, but also a cultural thing.

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea. You'd have to ask somebody who speaks both Chinese and English fluently, and who has a good understanding of both cultures. But I will say that "you are not a *Sean* or *David*" makes no sense to me in any real way. There is really no correlation ***at all*** between what somebody is named and who they are. To say there should be is a kind of stereotyping that can be dangerous. At best, names range from plain to odd to esoteric. It's the nature of the name itself that should be focused on, not if it it fits a person's appearance or mannerism or not.

Comment: I don't even know if translating a name is good in principle or not. Why not just pick an English name you like? Lots of people change their names because they don't like the one they had before. (But, again, I'm *only* expressing my personal opinion. And that could be at odds with Chinese cultural assumptions too.)

Comment: You want something that is pronounced exactly like your family name? or just something close?
The only thing pronounced like your family name is the letter G. Some people do use a letter as a name.

Comment: So I guess misunderstood the principle of naming and worried to much about the "unspoken rules" that I imaged, typical Chinese :( Then I will pick a plain name that sounds good to me :)

Comment: @KieranJackCommanda I'm looking for a first name that sounds OKey ahead of my family name ("G"), for example "John G" sounds wired...

Comment: Rather than just use a letter, you could spell it _Gee_, (which happens to exist as an English surname).

Comment: A Hong Kong friend of mine chose "Bartholomew" on the grounds that teachers had difficulty pronouncing it and thus he would be asked fewer questions.

Comment: tchrist's answer gives a good explanation. Sometimes names are chosen because they remind parents of family members or close friends. Sometimes first names are chosen because they sound harmonious with  the family's last name. Sometimes names have  religious origins, some archaic, exotic, historic, or are just very plain words.

Comment: @Greybeard Young Bartholomew Simpson's little sister Lisa would have recommended Thucydides to your friend instead . :)

Comment: If it were up to me, I'd go with Joe, Joad, Joel, Jody, or George.

Answer (score 4):

I don’t know what your Chi­nese name is, whether us­ing Chi­nese
char­ac­ters or in the Pinyin al­pha­bet that works bet­ter for
Western read­ers, but you need to know some­thing very im­por­tant
about our English-speak­ing cul­ture: **English names al­most never
‘mean’ some­thing the way Chi­nese names do**, like how 偉 *wěi*
means ‘great’ or 勇 *yǒng* means ‘brave’. That’s why many Chi­nese
peo­ple have those names, but it does not work that way for us. Our
per­sonal names have no in­trin­sic mean­ing of their own, so there
can be no mean­ing-based trans­la­tion pos­si­ble.

So if you’re 周到 *Zhōu Dao* or 孝道 *Xiào Dao* or some­thing else,
this al­most cer­tainly ‘means’ some­thing to you that could not
have a mean­ing­ful trans­la­tion into English no mat­ter how
thought­ful or pi­ous a good son you might be in your own
name-re­lated mind.

Some­times peo­ple are named for fa­mous peo­ple with that name
like *Cae­sar* or *Cleopa­tra*, but this is not all that com­mon.
Nam­ing some­one some­thing that has its own mean­ing like *Rock*
or *Prince* is un­com­mon, es­pe­cially in boys. In girls, you
some­times get flower names like *Daisy* and *Rose* or virtue names
like *Faith* and *Char­ity*. This may be a bit less un­com­mon in
Span­ish-speak­ing cul­ture than in English-speak­ing cul­ture, but
ei­ther way it still is­n’t all that su­per-com­mon here.

I don’t know why you would not sim­ply go by your real name writ­ten
out in Pinyin, but you prob­a­bly have your rea­sons. For ex­am­ple,
趙 *Zhào* and 著 *zhāo* and 周 *Zhōu* and 孝 *xiào* are all com­pletely
dif­fer­ent words, as too are 祷 *dǎo* and 道 *dao*, so per­haps
it is one that when pro­nounced with­out the cor­rect tones sounds
like a to­tally dif­fer­ent word in Chi­nese, and this turns out
to some­how be ‘not a nice word’ and so you quite un­der­stand­ably
don’t care to hear
your­self called that un­pleas­ant thing even out of pure ig­no­rance.

Peo­ple from Ja­pan or In­dia sel­dom make up names for Western­ers
to call them in­stead of us­ing their real names, but it is not
un­com­mon for Chi­nese peo­ple to do this. If for what­ever rea­son
you truly find your real name un­ac­cept­able in our mouths, then
per­haps you could choose some sound-se­quence that’s closer to
your name and which is an ac­tual Western name that peo­ple would
ac­tu­ally rec­og­nize and re­mem­ber as a name, like ‘Joe-Doe Jee’
or even ‘Jojo Gee’ be­cause *Jojo* is a fa­mil­iar and friendly
name for us, usu­ally a nick­name for *Jonathan*, *John*, or *Joseph*.

## Sum­mary

But my own per­sonal opin­ion, which is worth lit­tle to noth­ing, is that
you should con­tinue try­ing to use some­thing as close to your ‘real
name’ as our sim­pli­fied
[Ro­man writ­ing sys­tem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_alpha%C2%ADbet)
and the [nar­row rules of **English phono­tac­tics**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_phonology#Phonotactics)
can ap­prox­i­mate.

Peo­ple of good in­tent will al­ways do their best to honor your
per­sonal name, what­ever you choose.

Comment: The reason that I want an English name is, the current name does give people pronunciation troubles, especially in the public, that was a bit awkward. For example, when my German teacher tried to introduce me to a presentation, pinyin becomes puzzle words, while they have no trouble speaking an English name correctly.

Comment: After had make sure that there is no meaning implied by any English names, I will stick with my Chinese name :) It wouldn't be a problem for pinyin readers if I simply add an IPA note aside it.

Comment: @DingoStiglitz I have Chinese students and I have trouble pronouncing hanyu Pinyin. It's not intuitive for us. Have you considered a phonetical transliteration of your name that people where you live now would naturally pronounce correctly? Of course, I say this just as an additional option, not that you should change your name because of our ignorance.